# Adding template content to my footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm trying to add a footer content I found from a template into my slideout footer. Right now the template footer is covering the width of the entire page; I'm trying to fit it within the slideout footer. You can see the entire code on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/erodriguez2385/pen/ZbqQXj) The code isn't loading at the moment, not sure why. Thanks in advance.

```
 <div class="copyright">
   <p class="hidden-xs"> &copy; Copyright </p> 
 </div>


 <div  class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div id="footerSlideContainer">
    <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>      
    <div id="footerSlideContent">


     <footer>


<div class="footer-01">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <br>
          <h2 class="centered">THANKS FOR VISITING US</h2>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-lg-4">

            <h3>Latest Tweets
            </h3>


            <div id="example1"></div>
            <h4>Watch me on Periscope</h4>
            <a href="#" class="periscope-on-air" data-size="large">@Periscope</a> 
          </div><!-- col -->

          <div class="col-lg-4 border">

          </div><!-- col -->

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h3> Subscribe </h3>


            <p>Subscribe for the latest newsletters and updates</p>


            <div id="mc_embed_signup" class="mailchimp">
              <form action="..." method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate form-inline" target="_blank" novalidate> 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter email">
                  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn__bottom--border mailchimp__btn" data-style="shrink" data-horizontal>        
                </div>

                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="..." value=""></div>                          
              </form>
              <span class="form_nospam">No spam</span>  
            </div><!--End mc_embed_signup--> 
          </div><!-- col -->

        </div><!-- row -->

      </div><!-- container -->
      </div>
     </footer>
      <hr class="container">

      <div class="container">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alwayssunny/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/alwayssunny?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/allisondanger/its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia-intro" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x"></i></a>

        <div class="pull-right">
         <iframe width="100px" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/226657681&amp;color=999999&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"> </iframe>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is code after i fixed at

```
[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpYoeW][1]
```

The problem is your js section is invalid

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for fixing it. I appreciate it.